# SonarQube can't find the project configuration path

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Anyone knows how to figure this out?

```
C:\sonar-runner\bin\..
SonarQube Runner 2.3
Java 1.7.0_45 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Windows Server 2012 6.2 amd64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: C:\sonar-runner\bin\..\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
INFO: Default locale: "pt_BR", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Work directory: C:\sonar-runner\bin\.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.0
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 7.425s
Final Memory: 6M/31M
INFO: -----
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknow
n': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources
```

For some reason the SonarQube can't find the configuration project path
its return NONE from the INFO.
I already have the file in the conf path of the sonar-runner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read carefully the [doc page "Analyzing with SonarQube Runner"](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner), you can read:

```
Run the following command from the project base directory to launch the analysis:
```

The most important part is **"from the project base directory"**. This should answer your question.

Comment: The link to the external article is dead. What is the solution exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Important: the name of the project configuration file must be:
"sonar-project.properties" (not sonar-scanner.properties)

And you have to launch the `sonar-scaner` command from the path of your project.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add Project config file in the base directory.

That is ***C:\sonar-runner\bin***